# Как преобразовать значение из секундомера

Tags: javascript, html

Я нашел секундомер для своего сайта, чуть подкорректировал и дальше еще буду, но я застрял на одном моменте, так как не могу полностью разобраться в коде. Вкратце как я хочу сделать: получить при нажатии кнопки время, преобразовать его в миллисекунды (чтобы потом можно было это число сравнивать с другими) и это значение занести в БД, но вообще не знаю, как преобразовать(

Секундомер:

```js
function trim(string) {
  return string.replace(/\s+/g, " ").replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*)$/g, '');
}
var init = 0;
var startDate, thisDate, tdiff;
var clocktimer;
var sum = 0;

function clearFields() {
  init = 0;
  clearTimeout(clocktimer);
  document.clockform.clock.value = '00:00:00:000';
  document.clockform.label.value = '';
}

function clearALL() {
  clearFields();
  document.getElementById('marker').innerHTML = '';
  sum = 0;
  document.getElementById('markerSum').innerHTML = '';
}

function timeToStr(t) {
  var ms = t % 1000;
  t -= ms;
  ms = Math.floor(ms / 1);
  t = Math.floor(t / 1000);
  var s = t % 60;
  t -= s;
  t = Math.floor(t / 60);
  var m = t % 60;
  t -= m;
  t = Math.floor(t / 60);
  var h = t % 60;
  if (h < 10) h = '0' + h;
  if (m < 10) m = '0' + m;
  if (s < 10) s = '0' + s;
  if (ms < 10) ms = '0' + ms;
  return h + ':' + m + ':' + s + '.' + ms;
}

function startTIME() {
  thisDate = new Date();
  tdiff = thisDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
  var str = timeToStr(tdiff);
  if (init == 1) document.clockform.clock.value = str;
  clocktimer = setTimeout("startTIME()", 10);
}

function findTIME() {
  if (init == 0) {
    startDate = new Date();
    startTIME();
    init = 1;
  } else {
    sum += tdiff;
    var str = trim(document.clockform.label.value);
    document.getElementById('marker').innerHTML = (str == '' ? '' : str + ': ') +
      document.clockform.clock.value + '<br>' + document.getElementById('marker').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('markerSum').innerHTML = 'Всего: ' + timeToStr(sum);
    clearFields();
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="clockform">
  <p>Время:
    <input name="clock" id="t" size="12" maxlength="12" value="00:00:00:000">
    Метка:
    <input name="label" size="12" maxlength="40" value="">
    <input name="starter" type="button" value="Старт/Стоп" onclick="findTIME()">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input name="clearer" type="button" value="Сбросить всё" onclick="clearALL()">
  </p>
  <p id="markerSum"></p>
  <p id="marker"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var str = "11:03:04.218";

var s = str.split(/:|\./); // Разбиваем строку в массив по ключевым символам : или .
// На выходе будет ["11", "03", "04", "218"]

console.log( `Час ${s[0]}, Мин ${s[1]}, Сек ${s[2]}, мл ${s[3]}` );

var milli = ( s[0] * 3600 + s[1] * 60 + +s[2] ) * 1000 + +s[3]; 
// Плюсик перед строкой - превращает её в число. Иначе "1" + "1" === "11"

console.log( milli );
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)